# HTML5 validation on ARIA trees

Tags: html, validation, tree, wai-aria

I am using http://validator.w3.org/nu/ to perform HTML5 validation on my document. I don't understand why I get a validation error on the following code. I checked http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#treeitem and thought it was ok to place an li element with role="treeitem" inside an element ul with role="group". The nu validator tells me it is not allowed. I'd like to know if nu validator is correct in his verdict, and if so, where can we find the information about the schema for ARIA trees that stipulates that. Thank you.

Sample code that does not validate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Trees</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="label_1">Fruits and vegetables</h1>
    <ul id="tree" role="tree" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="label_1">
      <li role="treeitem" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#">Fruits</a>
        <ul id="tree1_1" role="group">
          <li role="treeitem"><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
          <li role="treeitem"><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem">
        <a href="#">Vegetables</a>
        <ul id="tree1_2" role="group">
          <li role="treeitem"><a href="#">Carrots</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`role="group"` is definitely allowed on `ul` elements. [The HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#table-aria-weak) spec currently reflects this as well. Validator.w3.org/nu/ and http://validator.w3.org/ both corectly treat this as valid. Validator.nu still seems to flag it as invalid though.

Regardless of validation, using nested trees is not the right choice here. It might pass the validator, but that's most likely just because it's allowed to nest widgets (just like you can have a slider or text field nested in a tree item). But they are still treated as separate widgets, not as the single, composite widget that a tree is supposed to be. The inner tree would not be part of the outer tree's structure, it would just be just a separate widget that happens to be nested in one of its tree items.

Answer (score 0):

On your line 13 and line 19 you need to have role = tree and not role=group

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Trees</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1 id="label_1">Fruits and vegetables</h1>
    <ul id="tree" role="tree" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="label_1">
  <li role="treeitem" aria-expanded="true">
    <a href="#">Fruits</a>
    <ul id="tree1_1" role="tree">
      <li role="treeitem"><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
      <li role="treeitem"><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="treeitem">
    <a href="#">Vegetables</a>
    <ul id="tree1_2" role="tree">
      <li role="treeitem"><a href="#">Carrots</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The validator does choke on role=group because of  [Group Definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#group) and if you read between the lines the list items are not in there. you have treeitem in your list so role would be tree and not group.

Comment: Disagree with this, it may validate, but it's no longer correct ARIA. The ARIA spec is pretty clear that group should be used to group interior treeitems. (Possible danger with putting `tree` in the interior is that if the user has focus on some interior node and asks the screenreader to report on the state of the entire tree, it may traverse upwards to first ancestor `tree`, and assume that that is the entire tree, missing other branches.) While it's often useful to think of trees recursively in implementation, as far as the user is concerned, there's a single *tree control* here.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The validator behaviour does seem a bit odd. The WAI-ARIA spec does seem to allow group as a container for treeitem.

On the other hand [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#table-aria-weak) does not allow "group" to be a role on the `<ul>` element. It must be either "directory", "list", "listbox", "menu", "menubar", "tablist", "toolbar", "tree" or "presentation"; yet the validator does not complain about that.

Either way, it seems you should use "tree" rather than "group".

Comment: With role=tree, it does validate. Thank you for the spec link that reflects that. My concern was that most examples I saw were putting the construction with the role=group on the inner uls.

Comment: `role=tree` on the inner items may validate, but I think it then ends up being incorrect use of ARIA, which could cause problems for screenreaders and their users (somewhat defeating the purpose of using ARIA in the first place...). Seems that `role=tree` should only be on the outermost element that represent the entire control; the spec does specifically mention use of `group` for interior subtrees. Looks like a validator bug.

Comment: I suspect there may also be a spec bug here; the [ARIA roles spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#treeitem) is pretty clear that `treeitems` can be contained in a `group`. Given that `li` elements can be `treeitem`s [from the HTML5 draft spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#table-aria-weak), it follows that the parent of an `li` - ie `ul` or `ol` *must* be capable of being `group`. My understanding is that the ARIA roles spec is the more mature of these two docs, with the table of allowable roles being relatively newer, this would appear to be an omission.

Comment: @BrendanMcK - You could be right. Do you have a citation as to why you think screen readers would have a problem with nested role="tree"s?

Comment: @Alochi - it's common task for code to want to navigate from an element to the overall control (usually by traversing up the DOM), and then get the overall control's state - eg find the current selected item(s), or deliver total item count. When you allow nesting of tree, it's ambiguous as to which tree corresponds to what the end-user perceives as the overall ui widget, so code might stop early (especially since current ARIA spec suggests this is a valid approach). Recursive definition is a useful impl technique, but users still relate to there being a single UI "tree control" present.

Comment: @Alochi: also, in the [ARIA Implementation guide](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-implementation/), DOM elements with role of `tree` are expected to map to platform accessibility API roles of ROLE_SYSTEM_OUTLINE (MSAA), ROLE_TREE (IAcc2), AxOutline (OSX/iOS) - all of these represent *entire* tree controls, not subsets, so this also suggests that the ARIA `tree` role should have similar semantics.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div role="application"> 

<h2 id="label_1">Foods</h2> 
<ul id="tree1" class="tree" role="tree" aria-labelledby="label_1"> 
  <li id="fruits" role="treeitem" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">Fruits 
    <ul role="group"> 
      <li id="oranges" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Oranges</li> 
      <li id="pinapples" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Pineapples</li> 
      <li id="apples" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false">Apples 
        <ul role="group"> 
          <li id="macintosh" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Macintosh</li> 
          <li id="granny_smith" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false">Granny Smith 
            <ul role="group"> 
              <li id="Washington" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Washington State</li> 
              <li id="Michigan" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Michigan</li> 
              <li id="New_York" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">New York</li> 
            </ul> 
          </li> 
          <li id="fuji" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Fuji</li> 
        </ul> 
      </li> 
      <li id="bananas" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Bananas</li>     
      <li id="pears" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Pears</li>     
    </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li id="vegetables" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="true">Vegetables 
    <ul role="group"> 
      <li id="broccoli" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Broccoli</li> 
      <li id="carrots" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Carrots</li> 
      <li id="lettuce" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false">Lettuce 
      <ul role="group"> 
          <li id="romaine" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Romaine</li> 
          <li id="iceberg" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Iceberg</li> 
          <li id="butterhead" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Butterhead</li> 
      </ul> 
      </li> 
      <li id="spinach" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Spinach</li>     
      <li id="squash" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="true">Squash 
        <ul role="group" > 
          <li id="acorn" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Acorn</li> 
          <li id="ambercup" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Ambercup</li> 
          <li id="autumn_cup" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Autumn Cup</li> 
          <li id="hubbard" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Hubbard</li> 
          <li id="kobacha" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Kabocha</li> 
          <li id="butternut" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Butternut</li> 
          <li id="spaghetti" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Spaghetti</li> 
          <li id="sweet_dumpling" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Sweet Dumpling</li> 
          <li id="turban" role="treeitem" tabindex="-1">Turban</li> 
        </ul> 
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul> 

</div>
```